# Stable, fast and fault-tolerant torrent client for Linux

Tags: linux, desktop-client, bittorrent

I'm looking for a good torrent client for Linux. Most clients I've tried (Transmission, Deluge) often "forget" about completed jobs and starts full recheck for an unknown reason, it is very annoying. Other wishes:

- The client *must* support location renaming (Transmission does not).
- It should be lightweight (don't suggest Vuze).
- It should be tolerant to disk plugging/unplugging, poor network connection, etc. and resume download jobs automatically.
- It should be pretty fast. For some reason average download speed with all Linux clients I've tried is much worse than with uTorrent on Windows on the same PC.

Comment: uTorrent is using [Micro Transport Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol), maybe this is why it is faster that normal torrent

Answer (score 7):

I'm currently using [rtorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) with the [rutorrent](https://code.google.com/p/rutorrent/) front-end.

The nice things about it are that it's *insanely fast*, uses very little resources on the system it runs on, and with the web user interface, is as good as a local client.

However, rtorrent on its own can be a little hard to use:

[image: rTorrent Konsole UI]

and it lacks RSS feed support. I use rutorrent as a front end, with an RSS plugin

[image: rutorrent UI]

Even without UTP support, it's blisteringly fast, and after the initial setup works perfectly — I have this running on an old PC which does my downloads and I manage it remotely.

I do note that this doesn't seem to have any form of authentication for the web UI, so if you're running one on a public-facing server, secure it appropriately!

Comment: I switched to this *from* qbitorrent. Basically rtorrent is fast but hard to use. rutorrent is just a nice skin over it. There is no reason you can't use rtorrent on its own in screen or on a terminal, other than needing to remember how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

My current choice is [qBittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/) ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QBittorrent)), *in general, I like it and it conforms most of my needs:* it is lightweight, fault-tolerant and supports location renames.

However, QBitTorrent isn't as fast as I would like it to be, also, it emits too much warning messages when something goes wrong (for example, a hard drive is unplugged).

[image: qBittorent Screenshot]

<sup>Click to view in higher resolution</sup>

Comment: I'd add that this is based on the *other* libtorrent (libtorrent rasterbar), and supports a lot of things newer varients of bitorrent support. While my *specific* needs weren't met (like being able to add rss feeds headless), its a great client. Its also worth noting you can run this headless as qbitorrent-nox and administer is purely through the webui.